# php mongodb optimization sort query

Tags: php, mongodb, query-optimization, php-mongodb

i need to find the most recent element, the field "data_caricamento" save the date.
so i made a index with MognoDb shell:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"data_caricamento": -1})
```

and with the php code below i have what i need

```
$cursor=$collection->find();
    $cursor->sort(array("data_caricamento"=> -1));
    $cursor->limit($n);
```

but i think that should be a better way to do it,
for example there is a way to query the directly the index?
thx.

Answer (score 1):

> there is a way to query the directly the index?

Sort of. You can do a covered query here by doing:

```
$cursor = $collection
    ->find(array(), array('_id' => 0, 'data_caricamento' => 1))
    ->sort(array("data_caricamento" => -1))
    ->limit($n);
```

That will query only the index.

Comment: but still  sort even if the index is yet sorted. so the complexity not changed

Comment: @user3535936 wehat do you mean? The index is already sorted, your just reading from the place in the index

Comment: but on your code still have 3 command on the pipe find->sort->limit
so i ask myself if it will improve performance

Comment: @user3535936 yes all I have done is added projection to let MongoDB know what it needs to pick out allowing it to say: "I don't need to look at the records to know what to pick"

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hint. And if you want to check whether the indexes got used by your query use explain().

```
....
$collection->find()->sort(array('data_caricamento'=>1))->hint(array('data_caricamento'=>1));
print_r($cursor->explain());
```

This will help you see that your queries are hitting index for faster search and sorting!
Cheers!